# Else does not work in selection of $row

Tags: php, if-statement, row

I want to check if user has set his gender. If not, it will display the 1st echo. If yes, it'll display the echo of his gender.
Problem is that the page shows only the 1st echo even though there IS set gender in database... I really don't know why it is not working...
My code:

```
    <?php 


    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $sql = "
         SELECT gender FROM members WHERE username = ?";
         $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($username);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
                                    if($row['gender'] == ""){
                                            echo "You have not selected your gender yet."; // This is the 1st echo and this is the only one that is displayed
                                    } else {
                                            echo "You selected that you are {$row['gender']}."; // This is not displayed no matter what...
                                    }
    }
    ?>
```

What I have wrong?

Comment: Is this is the full source code? if not post the full source code of your php script file.

Comment: @Faraj Farook - That's actually full php code for this action... I don't think you need connection because other stuff works fine

Comment: I believe there is an underlying framework code whcih you have not posted here. On that belief, can u do a var_dump for $row variable and post the value.

Comment: @FarajFarook - How to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a php expert, but I think this code would work better for you as I don't think that $row contains anything (I don't see where it's being set anywhere, and according to the docs, `bind_result` doesn't work that way anyway):

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT gender FROM members WHERE username =  ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($gender);

while ($stmt->fetch()){
    if(empty($gender)){
            echo "You have not selected your gender yet.";
        } else {
            echo "You selected that you are " . $gender;
        }
    }
```

EDIT

Used `empty()` instead of `= ""` in case nulls are returned for $gender.

EDIT 2

I noticed that you don't ever use `$sql`.  I updated the code for the proper syntax, assuming that your database connection is called `$mysqli`.

Might want to check the docs here: https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: it pops out the echo You selected that you are 1 o.O

Comment: If you look in your table in the database, what's in the field?  Is it something like "Male", "M", or 1?

Comment: I'm asking because the `gender` field could contain the foreign key for another table called `genders` or something like that.

Comment: Male.. I tried to define $gender with ´$gender = "SELECT gender FROM members WHERE username = ?";´  and ´$gender = $row['gender'];´ but still the same..

Comment: I updated my answer.  You've got some syntax issues going on.